# Got 0 on this question, need to know how it's done

Tags: calculus

Solve 2^(x+5) - 2^(x+1) = 45 . Find x

I tried solving it using logs and got a log in my answer but I guess that was wrong. Any tips here or something that I missed?

Comment: Can you show us your solution and tell why you think it is wrong? Please edit your question to add details.

Comment: Generally, $\log(a+b)\ne\log(a)+\log(b)$, but I feel like you might have accidentally assumed this when you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$
y =2^x
$$
Then solve
$$
32y -2y =45
$$
For y, and then for x?

Answer (score 1):

$$45=2^{x+5}-2^{x+1}=32\cdot2^x-2\cdot2^x=30\cdot2^x\implies 2^x=\frac32\implies x=\frac{\log\frac32}{\log 2}$$

Comment: $= \log_2 3 - 1$

Comment: Ohhh so you did a^m*a^n=a^(m+n)?

Comment: Indeed so, @Joe .

Comment: Sweet I never would have though of that, thanks a bunch